# How to move Photoshop CS5 Production Premium to a new computer (when I've lost my disks)

Tags: adobe-cs5

I moved and cannot find my Photoshop CS5 Production Premium disks. One of my two allowed installation computers crashed. The other has CS5 Production Premium on it. I cannot find my disks to load my allowed second installation. I have my serial number; however, Adobe no longer offers a download of the program (which once downloaded I could activate with my serial number). I tried a download from a third party site: didn't work. How do I copy and transfer the program from one computer to another? (Computer with the files runs Windows 7. Computer needing the files runs Windows 8.1.)

Comment: This absolutely worked! First try and exactly as you described. THANK YOU! I have been looking for my Adobe disks for months without any luck. This solution was great. I very, very much appreciate you taking the time to provide the solution. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

1. [Sign in](https://www.adobe.com/account/sign-in.adobedotcom.html?returnURL=https://www.adobe.com/account.html) with your Adobe account or create a new one. As an alternative, visit the [Download a free trial of Acrobat XI Pro](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=acrobat_pro) page.

   This step is required to set the session cookies on your browser which grant you access to the trial(s).
2. Download the official Production Premium CS5 trial directly from Adobe:
   http://trials2.adobe.com/AdobeProducts/STVD/CS5/win32/ProductionPremium_CS5_LS7.7z
3. Extract the content of the `.7z` archive using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).
4. Install the program using your serial number. When everything is up and running, make a backup of the setup package.

### References

- [Adobe Direct Download Links Without Akamai Download Manager](http://technolux.blogspot.jp/2011/02/adobe-direct-download-links-less-akamai.html)
- [Free Adobe CS5 Trial Downloads: Direct Links (no Akamai Manager)](http://prodesigntools.com/all-adobe-cs5-direct-download-links.html)